# PHP Forms not inserting data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble with data not saving to a table, I've got the following code in a file called Register.php, I have enabled error_reporting to see any errors, but none are showing. My database is called Registration and the table is called users and is being hosted on GoDaddy

```
<?php
require 'Connections/Connections.php';
?>

<?php
if(isset($_Post['Register'])) {

    session_start();
    $FName = $_POST['First_Name'];
    $LName = $_POST['Last_Name'];
    $Username = $_POST['Username'];
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $PW = $_POST['Password'];

    $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO users (Fname, Lname, Username, Email, Password)Values('{$Fname}', '{$LName}', '{$Username}', '{$Email}', '{$PW}')");

}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
<link href="Style/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" name="RegisterForm" id="RegisterForm">

    <div class="FormElement">
        <input name="First_Name" type="text" required="required"    class="TField" id="First_Name" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>

    <div class="FormElement">
        <input name="Last_Name" type="text" required="required" class="TField" id="Last_Name" placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>

    <div class="FormElement">
        <input name="Username" type="text" required="required" class="TField" id="Username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>

    <div class="FormElement">
        <input name="Email" type="text" required="required" class="TField"   id="Email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>

    <div class="FormElement">
        <input name="Password" type="text" required="required" class="TField" id="Password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>

    <div class="FormElement">
        <input name="Register" type="submit" class="button" id="Register"        placeholder="Register">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code in the Connections.php just without my real username and password

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "Registration");

?>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: update -- "INSERT INTO users (Fname, Lname, Username, Email, Password)Values('$Fname', '$LName', '$Username', '$Email', '$PW')"

Comment: you are using procedural style and object oriented style..... !!!!!!!

Comment: PHP is case sensitive. `$_POST` needs to be in capitals. You have `if(isset($_Post['Register']))`

Comment: see -- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: Working now, Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know that your code will not work in PHP 7 (future version of PHP) and that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated since a long time ?

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7) Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) its really pretty easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the Connection.php

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD"); 
mysql_select_db("Registration");  //your data base name
```

And also you have to edit

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (Fname, Lname, Username, Email, Password)Values('$Fname', '$LName', '$Username', '$Email', '$PW')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Working now, Thank you very much!

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7) Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) its really pretty easy

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (Fname, Lname, Username, Email, Password)Values('$Fname', '$LName', '$Username', '$Email', '$PW')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7) Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) its really pretty easy