# Cannot insert form data into a MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I am trying to insert data submitted in a form, into a MySQL Database, and I can't see the problem in my code(except for MySQL injection, that I will work to resolve after actually being able to insert any data). I have searched in Stack Overflow, and found someone who probably worked by the same manual, but I work in localhost, he's on GoDaddy. [The solution given there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566626/php-forms-not-inserting-data-in-mysql) doesn't work for me.

Here is my code for the HTML and the PHP code:

```
<?php 
  require'connection/connect.php';
  ?>
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['Register'])){
      session_start();
      $Fname = $_POST['FirstName'];
      $Lname = $_POST['LastName'];
      $Email = $_POST['Email'];
      $pw = $_POST['Password'];


  $sql= $con->query("INSERT INTO user (Fname,Lname,Email,Password) values('{$Fname}', '{$Lname}', '{$Email}', '{$pw}')");
  }

  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html >
  <html>
  <head>
  <link href="css/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>Register</title>
  </head>

  <body>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">

    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <div id="NavBar">
       <nav>
       <ul>
       <li>
       <a href="Login.php">Login</a>
       </li>
       <li>
       <a href="Register.php">Register</a>
       </li>
       </ul>
       </nav>
  </div>

    </div>
    <div class="leftBody"></div>
    <div class="rightBody">
      <form  action="" method="post" name="RegisterForm" id="RegisterForm">
      <div class="FormElement">
      <input name="FirstName" id="FirstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="TField">
      </div><br>
       <div class="FormElement">
      <input name="LastName" id="LastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="TField">
      </div><br>
       <div class="FormElement">
      <input name="Email" id="Email" type="email" placeholder="E-Mail" class="TField">
      </div><br>
       <div class="FormElement">
      <input name="Password" id="Password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="TField">
      </div><br>
      <input name="Register" id="Register" type="button" value="Register" class="regButton">
      </form>

    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>


  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

**And this is my connection.php file:**
*That it does show that it connects.*

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dataBase="users";
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dataBase);
if (!$con) {
    die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

**And a picture of my database in phpMyAdmin:**
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUgOL.png)

I have tried also using this line like this for some reason, but to no avail.:

```
$sql= $con->query("INSERT INTO user
                          (Fname,Lname,Email,Password)   
                   values ('Fname', 'Lname', 'Email', 'pw')");
```

Comment: `('Fname', 'Lname', 'Email', 'pw')` you're trying to literally enter those values as strings rather than the POST arrays/variables. Guess what you're missing here? Clue: Think "money" ;-)

Comment: Check for errors via PHP and MySQL; you're not doing that.

Comment: Can you please describe error ? so we can identify that one and give you solution

Comment: You're mixing object oriented and procedural style for using mysqli http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: @GordonM Bad practice yes, but those work together.

Comment: Also, this code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: *"and found someone who probably worked by the same manual, but I work in localhost, he's on GoDaddy"* - This smells like you're accessing as `file:///file.xxx` rather than `http://localhost/file.xxx`.

Comment: Fred, i said i tried it, just to see if it inserts anything. and it  has not. Uttam panara, it shows no error.

Comment: First of all you have to change type of reset button type. like (<input name="Register" id="Register" type="submit">) so that form can submit.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it does not show code on the page, i echoed it to see if it connects.

Comment: @GrowingDev Ok, I see your submit button and should be an `submit` type, not `button` and Sanjiv Dhakal's answer picked up on that and I overlooked it. That should work.

Comment: WOW! i cant believe it. it was because of the type="button" error! it works fine now. thank you very much to all of you, and especially for you @UttamPanara for pointed out to me.

Comment: Most welcome dear...

Comment: @GrowingDev Btw, if you intend on going live with this, your code is open a serious SQL injection and probably storing passwords as plain text. It is not safe to use at the present moment.

Comment: @GrowingDev There's also no need to update your question as being solved. Accepting an answer automatically marks it as such. Welcome to Stack ;-) Oh and I rolled back your question to another revision.

Comment: change type "button" to "submit"

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

[Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i didn't see submit button that actually submit the form. So if i am not wrong please try to use

```
<input name="Register" id="Register" type="submit" value="Register" class="regButton">
```

Comment: This looks promising. I'll upvote if it works for them. I overlooked that in the question; good catch.

Comment: [*"WOW! i cant believe it. it was because of the type="button" error! it works fine now. thank you very much to all of you, and especially for you @UttamPanara for pointed out to me. – GrowingDev"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38766344/cannot-insert-form-data-into-a-mysql-database-using-php#comment64904410_38766344) - Yep, that was it alright. ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's it. and i have also updated the OP with this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

your code should be run

```
$sql= $con->query("INSERT INTO user 
                           (Fname,Lname,Email,Password)   
                     VALUES('$Fname', '$Lname', '$Email', '$pw')");
```

Comment: They said they already tried that. What do you think my "comment" was about. They had `values('{$Fname}', '{$Lname}', '{$Email}', '{$pw}')` also; same thing here.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)